# ASP.NET 2.0 Session terminating unexpectedly

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, session, iis

We have an ASP.NET 20 Web Application and all of sudden we start experiencing a weird session timeout which is kicking out the users from the system. 
The system also invokes WCFs that uses membership authentication and every other invocation we are getting this error:

> The message could not be processed. This is most likely because the action 'http://tempuri.org/MyWCFService' is incorrect or because the message contains an invalid or expired security context token or because there is a mismatch between bindings. The security context token would be invalid if the service aborted the channel due to inactivity. To prevent the service from aborting idle sessions prematurely increase the Receive timeout on the service endpoint's binding.

No code changes were performed over the application and I am clueless what could be the cause or how to trace this problem any help on those matters will mean a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of session state are you using?  If it's InProc, then perhaps the IIS Application Pool is recyling, which would clear out the sessions and could be a potential cause of your problem.

You should also check if there is anything in your Session_Start or Session_End events that could cause any problems, and if so, consider adding error handling and/or logging here.

Comment: Do you think change it to State Server will solve the problem?. The weird part is that the application has been working well for the last 2 years and we have not made any deployment or change.

Comment: @Veco That's probably what I would try, but you need to be careful when doing that as if you're storing any custom objects in session, they need to be marked as serializable or you'll get an error. It's also possible that the issue is something related to the WCF service, and the ASP.NET application's session isn't actually the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try to change

```
<security mode="None">
```

to

```
<security mode="Message">
```

in the config file

Comment: Security cannot be altered since it is a Production public site. Additional can you please explain why the asp.net site session could be affected by this as well?