# AppPool restarting on compiled website

Tags: asp.net, iis, application-pool

We have an ASP.NET 2.0 Web Application Pool running on .NET 3.5 and "*all of sudden*" we started to experience a weird session timeout which is kicking out the users from the system.

From the event viewer we can see a warning message saying that [app pool is restarting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23809025/3155120) due to an exception with no much detail on why. As you may guess session is **In Proc** and due to early mistakes in the application design using **state server** will require a lot of work and time which we do not have(I guess you never experienced that too) and also I am eager to find what is happening.

At some point we had decided to compile the site using: `Aspnet_compiler -v /WebApplication1` this was done in the server itself. When we put both versions to run the *compiled* and the *non-compiled* and we noticed the issue occurs way more often in the compile version than the non-compiled version. Like every 5 min. in the compiled  version vs 1 or 2 times a day in the non-compile.

What may be affecting the compiled version or forcing the app pool to restart?

Comment: IIS Version is **7.5**

Comment: I'm surprised that you think switching from InProc to StateServer is difficult-- every time I've done it it's just editing the webconfig. Switching from InProc to SQL is hard because you learn which objects weren't serializable. Since I'm speculating, I would guess that you are hitting an out of memory problem (which you will hit far earlier than the server's physical memory-- a few large objects and IIS will think a single request is about to take down the server-- so it recycles.)

Comment: Have you tried turning off Rapid Fail Protection?

Comment: Server has 16GB of memory ram and it is at 27% of use

Comment: Rapid Fail Protection... let me check on that. I didn't know about it

Comment: Also you could/should put Elmah into your project, any unhandled exceptions will get caught and you'll find out whats going on super quick. Who said anything about InProc or SessionState Server? I don't see why thats in your question?!